# How to get data request from link url in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to load data from this url: http://gateway.fpts.com.vn/monitor/realtime/?s=aaa using Javascript.

This url returns data in my browser as shown below:

[image: Screenshot - data as shown in a web browser]

Here is the code I tried:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>The jQuery Example</title>
      <script type = "text/javascript" src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id= "stage"></div>
        <script type = "text/javascript" language = "javascript">
         var url = "http://gateway.fpts.com.vn/monitor/realtime/?s=aaa"
        $.ajax({
          url: url,
          cache: false,
          method: "GET",
        })
          .done(function( html ) {
            $( "#stage" ).append( html );
          });
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

But I am getting this Error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://gateway.fpts.com.vn/monitor/realtime/?s=aaa&_=1465298988417. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Read about jQuery.ajax() here http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making a [cross-origin http request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) as you are requesting data from a domain `http://gateway.fpts.com.vn` which is different form that of your html file shown in question, say it `http://www.requesting-server.com`

To allow [cross-origin resource sharing](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/), you should set following header on the requested server `http://gateway.fpts.com.vn`.

To allow requests from any domain, use `*` as a wildcard (less secure):

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

or

To allow requests from a particular domain:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.requesting-server.com
```

You can also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource) post which addresses the same issue.

Comment: I tried same: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS
error  25 Uncaught ReferenceError: handler is not defined

Comment: Can you tell me how you are setting the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header at the server `http://gateway.fpts.com.vn`? You can share code / screenshot or relevant information in the question. Do not delete the original question text. Just at the bottom add details with a "Edit:" note.

Comment: Which means that I have to set up header on the server, the server accepts CORS returns response?

Comment: Hi @Orions! I use MVC. I write a function getData: make request with WebRequest, and use StreamReader read data form url. I pass data from controller to view :). It same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10565090/getting-the-response-of-a-asynchronous-httpwebrequest

Comment: Orions! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Orions comment (https://stackoverflow.com/a/37678620/633781), you need to provide following header in your request to a server, to make it work:

```
Origin: <your domain, e.g. http://example.com>
```

As far as I remember, jQuery does this automatically for you. Nevertheless, you can check the request headers in your browser's Dev tools to make sure it does. You can add your own headers to requests made with jQuery, though (https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: You are right in "jQuery does this automatically for you"

Answer (score 0):

You have to import jquery library from below link to use this code. https://jquery.com/download/

```
$.get( "http://gateway.fpts.com.vn/monitor/realtime/?s=aaa", function( data ) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Hi @Dhval thank you for answer! But have a error:"XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://gateway.fpts.com.vn/monitor/realtime/?s=aaa&_=1465298988417. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access."

Comment: Please  prefer  this for No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28547288/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-err

Answer (score 0):

You can make an ajax request an then get the data, something like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://gateway.fpts.com.vn/monitor/realtime/?s=aaa",
}).done(function(data) {
  $("body").html(data);
});
```

Make sure to include jquery if you use this.

Comment: Hi @Bjørn Nyborg thank you for answer! But have a error:"XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://gateway.fpts.com.vn/monitor/realtime/?s=aaa&_=1465298988417. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access."

Comment: That is because its a cross-domain request. 
Try adding dataType: 'jsonp',

Answer (score 0):

Because your data is in `JSON` form, you can use a shorthand for that using [`$.getJson()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/). Download [jQuery library](http://jquery.com/download/) and include on top of every script. Then place the following snippet in a separate script below the jQuery library.

```
(function($){
  $(function(){
      $.getJson( "http://gateway.fpts.com.vn/monitor/realtime/?s=aaa", function(data) {        
          console.log(data);
          // do something with data....        
      });
  });
})(jQuery || window.jQuery);
```

Comment: Hi @Rohit416 thank you for answer!
but have error: Uncaught TypeError: $.getJson is not a function

Comment: Have you included `jQuery` on top?

Comment: I included on top.