# Failing to catch the response from Task.Factory.FromAsync

Tags: c#, sql

I have this object

```
public class ObjectList
{
    public string idreturn { get; set; }
}
```

While running asynchronous requests with `Task.Factory.FromAsync`, I'm failing to catch the response

```
foreach (var obj in ObjectList)
{
    var wreq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Convert.ToString(getURL));
    var taskResp = Task.Factory.FromAsync<WebResponse>(wreq.BeginGetResponse, wreq.EndGetResponse, null);
    taskResp.ContinueWith(tsk => new StreamReader(tsk.Result.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd().Trim())
            .ContinueWith((Task<string> trs) => {
                obj.idreturn = trs.Result.ToString();
            });
}

return JsonHelper.JsonSerializer(ObjectList);
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you getting any exception ? If yes, include the exception details / stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

You're starting an asynchronous operation and then moving on and serializing the object before the asynchronous operation has finished.

Rather than using `ContinueWith` you should `await` the value returned from `FromAsync` to get the results, that way the rest of the code won't continue on until after the request has finished.  If you want the requests to all happen in parallel you can construct all of the tasks and then `await Task.WhenAll` to run the serialization code after the requests have all finished.

Comment: How should I implement the "await" in this code?
for: 
       var taskResp = await Task.Factory.FromAsync<WebResponse>(wreq.BeginGetResponse, wreq.EndGetResponse, null);

I'm getting : Error CS4032
The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task<SqlString>'.WebRequestCLR.sqlproj

Comment: @YanivBenYohana If you're not familiar with it at all you should read through a tutorial on the topic.  Covering all of what you need to know is beyond the scope of a single SO answer.  That code code that you have that is just what you need to be doing, yes, the error that you have with the code tells you precisely what else you need to change.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to James Manning answer in [Getting the Response of a Asynchronous HttpWebRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10565090/getting-the-response-of-a-asynchronous-httpwebrequest) question I finally solved the problem.

```
  var task = MakeAsyncRequest(getURL);
  obj.smsidreturn = task.Result;
```