# C# sync function to async

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

How I can change this function to async with Framework 4.6.1? The DGV has a lot of data and blocks the rest of the processes.

DGV is updated every 30 seconds with timer.

any other solution do not block the next process until this is finnished?

I may have something wrong, I am starting in the world of programming and I have many things to learn.

```
private void FillTimes()
        {
            var strResponse = CallJson($"RESTAPI URL");
            if (strResponse != null)
            {
                var jResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonResults>(strResponse);

                BindingSource bsResults = new BindingSource();
                bsResults.DataSource = jResult.Results;

                if (bsResults.DataSource != null)
                {
                    DgvOnline.DataSource = bsResults.DataSource;
                }
            }
        }
```

CallJson

```
 private string CallJson(string strURL)
            {
                RestTiming rJson = new RestTiming();
                rJson.endPoint = strURL;
                rJson.token = apiToken;

                string strResponse = string.Empty;

                strResponse = rJson.makeRequest();

                return strResponse;
            }
```

ResTiming

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Timing
{
    public enum httpVerb
    {
        GET,
        POST,
        PUT,
        DELETE

    }
    class RestTiming
    {
        public string endPoint { get; set; }
        public string token { get; set; }
        public httpVerb httpMethod { get; set; }
        public string userName { get; set; }
        public string userPassword { get; set; }
        public string postJSON { get; set; }

        public RestTiming()
        {
            endPoint = string.Empty;
            token = string.Empty;
        }

        public string makeRequest()
        {
            if (InternetAvailable())
            {
                string strResponseValue = string.Empty;

                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(endPoint);

                request.Method = httpMethod.ToString();
                request.ContentType = "application/json";
                request.Accept = "application/json";
                request.Headers.Add("Authorization", token);
                request.UserAgent = @"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.106 Safari/537.36";

                if ((request.Method == "POST" || request.Method == "PUT") && postJSON != string.Empty)
                {
                    using (StreamWriter swJSONPayload = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
                    {
                        swJSONPayload.Write(postJSON);
                        swJSONPayload.Close();
                    }
                }

                HttpWebResponse response = null;

                try
                {
                    response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

                    // Process the response stream... (could be JSON, XML or HTML etc...)

                    using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        if (responseStream != null)
                        {
                            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                            {
                                strResponseValue = reader.ReadToEnd();
                            }// End of StreamReader
                        }
                    }// End of using ResponseStream

                }
                catch (WebException ex)
                {
                    if (ex.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError && ex.Response != null)
                    {
                        var resp = (HttpWebResponse)ex.Response;
                        if (resp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Unauthorized", "Unauthorized", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
                            Environment.Exit(1);
                        }
                    }
                }

                return strResponseValue;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        private static Boolean InternetAvailable()
        {
            try
            {
                using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
                {
                    using (client.OpenRead("http://www.google.com/"))
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What is `CallJson`? what is the code in this?

Comment: There is nothing here looks like it needs to be async. Perhaps CallJson depending on what it is doing.

Comment: Asynchrony is for managing latency. What is the high-latency operation here?

Comment: Updated the post with CallJson code

Comment: Maybe duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10928528/receiving-json-data-back-from-http-request (or any "Get JSON async in C#" posts)?

Comment: I recommend to use EventHandler to do your task. use timer once and disable it. re enable on eventhandler again.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not going to weigh in on whether your code should be async or not.

If you want the synchronous work to happen in a background thread, you can execute it using `Task.Run` as follows:

```
private async Task FillTimes()
{
    return Task.Run(() => {
    {
        var strResponse = CallJson($"RESTAPI URL");
        if (strResponse != null)
        {
            var jResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonResults>(strResponse);

            BindingSource bsResults = new BindingSource();
            bsResults.DataSource = jResult.Results;

            if (bsResults.DataSource != null)
            {
                DgvOnline.DataSource = bsResults.DataSource;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should also note, wrapping/offloading CPU bound workloads in the implementation of an `async` method is a code smell and is called *fake async*, its confusing, its not scalable, it uses up valuable thread-pool threads and can have unintended consequences. Even if this is IO bound, its very suspicious and should be warned against

Comment: @MichaelRandall Certainly. I completely agree. Most beginners are looking to StackOverflow for simple solutions to simple problems. StackOverflow isn't supposed to be an extensive curriculum. 

If your detailed answer and warnings are what the OP desires, then they can mark your answer as accepted. If the OP wants a simple answer that doesn't go into the numerous flaws and gotchas of `async/await/TPL` then this answer is perfect.

Comment: @MichaelRandall Well, what's the alternative to `Task.Run()` for CPU-bound computation? `BackgroundWorker`? No thank you.

Comment: @Joker_vD you missed the point, you just should wrap CPU bound in a task then call it an async method, let the method be syncronions let the caller call task run. For all the reasons I stated

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

If `CallJson` is *IO Bound* work then you could make that `async`, also you would append the `Async` suffix to the the method name to be consistent. Your resulting method would look like this.

```
private async Task FillTimes()
{
   var strResponse = await CallJsonAsync($"RESTAPI URL");
   if (strResponse != null)
   {
      var jResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonResults>(strResponse);

      BindingSource bsResults = new BindingSource();
      bsResults.DataSource = jResult.Results;

      if (bsResults.DataSource != null)
      {
         DgvOnline.DataSource = bsResults.DataSource;
      }
   }
}
```

And your `async` method would look like this

```
private async Task<responseType> CallJsonAsync(<something>)
{
    ... 

    await SomethingAsync(...);

    ...

    return something;
}
```

**Original**

> How I can change this function to async with Framework 4.6.1

There is no obvious *IO Bound* work, and no method that would lend itself towards an `async` call (that i can see).

So to answer the question, "*How I can change this function to `async`?*", the answer is you shouldn't, let it be synchronous.

If this does not update the *UI*, you could call this method from a `Task`, and `await` that

Answer (score 1):

**Updated**

```
  class RestTiming
  {
    public string endPoint { get; set; }
    public string token { get; set; }
    public httpVerb httpMethod { get; set; }
    public string userName { get; set; }
    public string userPassword { get; set; }
    public string postJSON { get; set; }

    public RestTiming()
    {
        endPoint = string.Empty;
        token = string.Empty;
    }

    public async Task<string> makeRequest() //1. Changed to async and return type
    {
        if (InternetAvailable())
        {
            string strResponseValue = string.Empty;

            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(endPoint);

            request.Method = httpMethod.ToString();
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.Accept = "application/json";
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", token);
            request.UserAgent = @"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.106 Safari/537.36";

            if ((request.Method == "POST" || request.Method == "PUT") && postJSON != string.Empty)
            {
                using (StreamWriter swJSONPayload = new StreamWriter(await request.GetRequestStreamAsync())) //2. changed to asynchronous call
                {
                    swJSONPayload.Write(postJSON);
                    swJSONPayload.Close();
                }
            }

            WebResponse response = null; //(a) updated

            try
            {
                response =await request.GetResponseAsync(); 

                // Process the response stream... (could be JSON, XML or HTML etc...)

                using (Stream responseStream =response.GetResponseStream()) //(b) updated
                {
                    if (responseStream != null)
                    {
                        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                        {
                            strResponseValue = await reader.ReadToEndAsync(); // (c) updated
                        }// End of StreamReader
                    }
                }// End of using ResponseStream

            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                if (ex.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError && ex.Response != null)
                {
                    var resp = (HttpWebResponse)ex.Response;
                    if (resp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Unauthorized", "Unauthorized", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
                        Environment.Exit(1);
                    }
                }
            }

            return strResponseValue;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static Boolean InternetAvailable()
    {
        try
        {
            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                using (client.OpenRead("http://www.google.com/"))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
```

Changes in the second method

```
private async Task<string> CallJson(string strURL) //1. Changed to async and return type
        {
            RestTiming rJson = new RestTiming();
            rJson.endPoint = strURL;
            rJson.token = apiToken;

            string strResponse = string.Empty;

            strResponse =await rJson.makeRequest(); //2. made asynchronous 

            return strResponse;
        }
```

The change in the first method

```
    private async Task FillTimes() // 1. Make async and change return type
    {
        var strResponse =await CallJson($"RESTAPI URL"); // 2. add await to make asynchronous
        ...
    }
```

Please let me know if this helps.
Additionally, check this link ([Getting the Response of a Asynchronous HttpWebRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10565090/getting-the-response-of-a-asynchronous-httpwebrequest))

Comment: Thanks you, but I have problems with the first method that you change, with the 3 and 4 changes. **3** you can not convert the type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task <System.Net.WebResponse>' into 'System.Net.HttpWebResponse'**4** "HttpWebResponse" does not contain a definition for "GetResponseStreamAsync"

Comment: I updated the code with comments, please try and let me know if it works.